# How to remove numbers from URL in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, numbers, url-rewriting

This is the code of my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^play/([0-9]+)_(.+)$ file.php?f=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

My Link is

sitename.com/play/399_Beauty_Barbie_hair

But, I want it to be like this

sitename.com/play/Beauty_Barbie_hair

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need another rule handling your new URI structure:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^play/([0-9]+)_(.+)$ file.php?f=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^play/(.+)$ file.php?f=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: not working
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^games/([0-9]+)_(.+)$ file.php?f=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^games/(.+)$ file.php?f=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

function file($id, $title) {
  if ($this->search_engine_friendly) {
   $title = str_replace($this->replace, $this->replacement, $title);
   return $this->site_url .'/'. $this->file_url .'/'. $id .'_'. $title ;
  } else {
   return $this->site_url .'/file.php?f='. $id;
  }
 }

Comment: Don't paste code here. Explain what's not working? Are you getting 404? Which URL is causing problem, as much details as possible about the problem will be better.

Comment: Thanks for your replay
i'm not getting 404 but nothing happen and url still with number like this sitename.com/play/399_Beauty_Barbie_hair, can you help please?

Comment: Do you want URL in browser to change to: `sitename.com/play/Beauty_Barbie_hair`? If that is so how will you get parameter `f` in your `file.php`?

Comment: i don't know, There is no solution?

Comment: You need to build some understanding around it first. If a URL you see in browser doesn't have an ID then internal URL will also not have it.